# Error: capability must be a valid BrowserStack App-Automate App URL

Tags: android, appium, browserstack, desiredcapabilities

With https://api-cloud.browserstack.com/app-automate/upload I had generated a hash for my hybrid android app.

I had set the desired capabillity in my program as follows:

```
caps.SetCapability("app", "bs://hash_which_is given_by_browserstack");
```

When running my program to test it on Browserstack the following error occurs:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: [app] capability must be a valid BrowserStack App-Automate App URL
```

What could be went wrong?

Answer (score 1):

As Ozone17 mentioned, making sure you're supplying an app of the right platform is a good tip (an ipa for iOS and an apk for Android).

Also, it seems to be okay for you, but if anybody gets the same issue, check whether you uploaded the app to the *app-automate* service, not *app-live*!
The url looks almost the same and it is easy to get mixed up.

Answer (score 0):

The error message "**[app] capability must be a valid BrowserStack App-Automate App URL**" indicates that the value specified for the 'app' capability is incorrect OR invalid. Ensure that the uploaded app is a valid IPA/APK file and is being run on the appropriate device (example, you might be passing app URL for an APK file for iOS devices).

If the device is correct, try uploading the application under test again using the following  REST API command:

```
curl -u "your_username:your_access_key" -X POST https://api-cloud.browserstack.com/app-automate/upload -F "file=@/path/to/app/file/Application-debug.apk"
```

Comment: The uploaded app is an hybrid Android app with App name 'MyApp' . com.apk. The device I'm using is an Android device.